# Is it bad practice to use -1 as an invalid value (for enums and possibly unkown values)

Tags: c, initialization

Is it a bad idea to use -1 as an invalid value for an enum value(for enumerations that start at 0 or greater). For uninitialized values or values that should no longer have a valid values.
What about for testing how functions deal with invalid

```
#define INVALID_ENUM_VALUE -1
```

What about setting a random uint value to -1 if its in an uninitialized/invalid(say a resource id).

```
#define INVALID_UNINT_VALUE -1
```

Are there potential issues with wraparound? It's not particularly likely a valid integer will have that value if the program is not very complicated and doesn't run for a long time. Should I use UINT_MAX? Give up and just use a bool to track valid state?

Comment: Well, it depends on what are the valid values. If you don't expect that large numbers - OK. If you don't expect to have 0 (for example - some timers), use 0 instead. If you expect to have some overflows (use the size of the int for some modulo operations), then -1 is not a good idea, etc. This really depends on a lot of things.

Answer (score 4):

If all integers are possible good values for in code, as they are for (say) addition, then using -1 (or any numeric value) to indicate errors or unknowns doesn't make sense - you need to use some other mechanism, or simply ignore errors.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the approaches I use:

- If you're using `enums`, add another value for "invalid state"
- If you have a function that returns, say, an `int`, either:

  - return a `struct` instead that has an extra field (eg. `valid_result` or `error`), or
  - take a pointer to an `int` that you modify for the result and have the return value report the error

Comment: What if its not your enum(library enum)?

Comment: @Roman - ah, then it's trickier, but these approaches might still apply. For example, if a library function could return any `int` (even -1), but you want to indicate an uninitialised value, you could still use a struct with an "initialised" flag to wrap the value. If you have a function that returns the value from such a function, but only if certain code paths are followed, you could still use either approach above. Does that make sense?